# Terraform Refresh after manual change

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

So here's what I'm trying to do

```
Given I changed a configuration in the load balancer
And I added that to my terraform declaration
When I run a plan there are zero changes which is expected
```

Do I need to refresh at this point to match my hardware state before applying?

Or when I run an apply this would just update the state?

Comment: Can you provide an example of your current TF code, what you changed manually and what outcomes do you get after the refresh?

Comment: terraform plan shows the difference between actual infra & terraform config files. As you have made changes to equalize terraform config files with actual infra, it will report no change will be made. terraform refresh-only, shows difference between actual infra & terraform state (NOT config) files; it will report a difference as terraform state file is out-of-sync with actual infra state until you do terraform apply refresh-state or terraform apply. Comparison: https://medium.com/code-oil/understanding-terraform-plan-apply-refresh-only-the-myths-and-fixing-drift-5963207a1df8#6ec9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you've changed the settings outside of Terraform *and* you've updated the Terraform configuration to match then indeed there's no extra step to run here: `terraform plan` should report that it detected the value changed outside of Terraform (assuming you're using Terraform v1.0.0 or later) but then report that it doesn't need to make any changes to match with the configuration.

Note also that in recent Terraform the `terraform refresh` command is still available but no longer recommended. Instead, you can use `terraform apply -refresh-only` to get a similar effect but with the opportunity to review the detected changes before creating a new state snapshot. In the situation you've described, a refresh-only apply like this will also allow you to commit the detected change as a new state snapshot so that future `terraform plan` won't re-report that it detected a change made outside of Terraform, which might avoid your coworkers being confused by this message when they make a later change.